# Reference from the article "Random Ordinary Differential Equations", by J.L. Strand

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-differential-equations

In the article [*Random Ordinary Differential Equations*](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82447522.pdf), Journal of differential equations 7, 538-553 (1970), by J.L. Strand, reference number 6 refers to his PhD thesis: *Stochastic Ordinary Differential Equations*, University of California (Berkeley), 1968. Reference number 5 is also a PhD thesis: *Random Ordinary Differential Equations*, University of California (Berkeley), 1968, by R. Edsinger.

Do you know how to obtain these two PhD theses?

Comment: Have you tried ProQuest?

Answer (score 1):

I'm J. L. Strand. I have a copy and I might have a copy of Edsinger's thesis. Send me an Email. There should also be a copy in the UCB math library.

dnartsipad@gmail.com

John Strand

Comment: This is great, thank you. would it be possible to make an electroonic copy and to make it available to a wider public?

Answer (score 0):

[WorldCat](http://www.worldcat.org/title/stochastic-ordinary-differential-equations/oclc/892818387&referer=brief_results) says Strand's thesis is [online.](https://search.proquest.com/docview/302237505) The ProQuest link only shows the first 20 pages, with the option to download the whole text (107 pages) if you have access to a library subscription or to pay a large fee ($ 38) if you do not.

Also according to [WorldCat](http://www.worldcat.org/title/random-ordinary-differential-equations/oclc/25830173), Edsinger's thesis is not online, you'll have to go through a library. (It's digitized by Hathi Trust, but not publicly available because of copyright restrictions.)